# Vector of numbers where merge sort is slow

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm starting to study sorting algorithms in Python.
Merge Sort has a complexity at best and worst cases \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)\$, I want generation a list where Merge Sort is slow but I would some complication. 
Could you help me with this problem?

This is the code:

```py
def mergeSort(l):

    #print("Splitting ",l)
    if len(l)>1:
        mid = len(l)//2
        lefthalf = l[:mid]
        righthalf = l[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)


        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i]<righthalf[j]:
                l[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                l[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            l[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            l[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    #print("Merging ",l)
    return
```

Comment: That's not really the purpose of this site. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594112/when-will-the-worst-case-of-merge-sort-occur) for how to create a worst case input for merge sort.